# MVCRazorToPDF Adding page header and footer on every pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvcrazortopdf

Can i make a header and footer on every pages created using MVCRazorToPDF Library 
On PDFLayout.cshtml file i am making a section for the body of PDF as

```
<body>
@RenderBody()
</body>
```

And in controller i am calling the action like

```
return new PdfActionResult(model, (writer, document) =>
        {
            document.SetPageSize(new Rectangle(233, 842, 90));
            document.NewPage();
        });
```

And my View.cshtml is like a normla html page

```
@model PDFLAbApp.Models.PdfExample
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PdfLayout.cshtml";
}
<h1>@Model.Heading</h1>
<p>
paragraph content repeated n times based on the model content [ its a foreach loop and page size is more than 2 
</p>
```